# highchart: add images to top of chart on every column

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Does anyone know if it's possible to create something like this in [Highcharts](http://highcharts.com):

[image: Highchart question]

It's about the weather icons on the top. I added them as a "scatter graph" which is nice, so the images/graph can be disabled. But I want them always at the top. For example: y=20px or something. Is it possible to do this with Highchart? I know set their data to "30 celcius" but that would mess up the graph if it the temperature would go up to 30 degrees.

Answer (score 9):

You can use a trick of having two x-axes, one with images and offset'ed to the top of the chart and one with the usual labels at the bottom:

```
xAxis: [{
    offset: -290,
    tickWidth: 0,
    lineWidth: 0,
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    labels: {
        x: 5,
        useHTML: true,
        formatter: function () {
            return '<img src="http://highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png"><img>&nbsp;';
        }
    }
}, {
    linkedTo: 0,
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
}],
```

Full example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZZ7Kd/)

[image]

Comment: i didn't know the existing of `useHTML` option. saved me a lot.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that you cannot use the data in your `series` in the formatter where you're setting the image (at least I didnt find a way to access them).

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution by chance because of a logging code I forgot to remove. You can access the data inside the method formatter using "this":

```
...
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        dataLabels: {
            useHTML: true,
            enabled: true,
            x: -50,
            y: -50,
            formatter: function(){
                console.log(this);
                return '<span>'+this.y+'</span><br/>'+this.series+'<img src="'+this.key+'" />';
            },
        }
    ...
```

This code surely isn't working, but shows up the idea, doesn't it?
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Given that highcharts is just SVG you can always go directly and manipulate the SVG to show the images you want, usually with just [CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html). You can inspect the chart with Chrome's web inspector and find the elements you want to style. I have to warn you though that having customized highcharts myself in the past has made upgrading to newer versions difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You can add another `scatter` plot to your `series` that contains specific `markers`: http://jsfiddle.net/ZZ7Kd/135/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Renderer.image() to add images in any place on chart

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.image()

Comment: Yes, here is an example of that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794682/highcharts-adding-clickable-image-to-every-xaxis-gridline/8801203#8801203