# Highcharts: Adding clickable image to every xAxis gridLine

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm building in some custom functionality where users can click on data points in a line chart to add notes to that date. This is a bit misleading as the notes aren't actually attached to the metrics themselves but rather the date it lands on. In other words, if I have 6 series on one line chart that spans the dates 01/01/12 - 01/08/12, a single note on 01/05/12 will apply to all 6 series. So, as you can imagine clicking on a data point on one of the 6 series or the date 01/05/12 would mislead the user to believe that this note would be applied to that data point, not the entire date and any series that lands on that date.

So, to remedy this usability issue I've decided that the best visual cue would be something like this:

[image]

There would be a clickable icon at the top of each xAxis gridLine that would need to scale with the xAxis gridLine (like if a user selects an area to zoom in on).

Suggestions on best way to pull this off? I only need a suggestion for how best to add the icon to every line... I have all post-click functionality already built.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Building on Mark's suggestion using `redraw` event to position the images and using `load` event to create them. Adding them on `load` is necessary to make them available during export and you would not want to create new images on each `redraw` either.

These chart events are used:

```
events: {
    load: drawImages,
    redraw: alignImages
}
```

In the `drawImages` function I'm using the inverse translation for the xAxis to position the images on the chart:

```
x = chart.plotLeft + chart.xAxis[0].translate(i, false) - imageWidth / 2,
y = chart.plotTop - imageWidth / 2;
```

and then adding them and setting a click handler, zIndex, pointer cursor:

```
chart.renderer.image('http://highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png', x, y, imageWidth, imageWidth)
    .on('click', function() {
        location.href = 'http://example.com'
    })
    .attr({
        zIndex: 100
    })
    .css({
        cursor: 'pointer'
    })
   .add();
```

In `alignImages` the `attr` function is used to set new x and y values for the images which are calculated the in the same way as in `drawImages`.

Full example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jnjqt/)

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Very nice solution!  I was not aware of the translate method.  Much cleaner than querying out of the DOM.

Comment: @Eolsson actually looking at your fiddle, if I had an array of dates, would you be able to show me how the for loop can work and loop over the array, and for each of these dates place the clickable icon into the xaxis? That may be easier than what i'm trying to do with comparing dates.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ideas.  First, I would use the chart [redraw](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#chart-events--redraw) event to know when the chart is being redrawn (say on a zoom).  Then second, explicitly place your images at the axis locations of interest.  To get those query directly out of the DOM.

Using jQuery:

```
$('.highcharts-axis') //return an array of the two axis.
```

They will have svg "text element" children with (x, y) positions.