# Custom Series Icons

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts

Is there a way to add a custom icon on top of a vertical line in highcharts?  I am looking to add these points at specific dates(day granularity.)  It seems that this would be best executed as a series; however, I don't see a way to append additional data to a data point.  I have looked through the documentation for render, plot lines, and plot bands... nothing really seems to help.  I'm even having difficulty finding just an example of adding a vertical line at a date.

[image]

As you can see in the above screenshot, the beaker and message icon are events that have happened at specific dates.  Does anyone know how to accomplish something like this in highcharts?  Thanks a lot for your assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding **scatter** plot to **series** with **markers**:

Under series:

```
        {
        type: 'scatter',
        showInLegend: false,
        data: [{}, {}, {}, {
            y: 200,
            marker: {
                symbol: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/snow.png)'
            }
        }, {
            y: 200,
            marker: {
                symbol: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png)'
            }
        }
```

Crop unnecessary part:

```
    yAxis: {
        max: 200,
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/j8Y6g/1/

---

Previous answer (Not resized properly):

[Highcharts API: Renderer.image](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.image)

```
}, function(chart) { // on complete
    chart.renderer.image('http://highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png', 410, 40, 20, 20).add();
    chart.renderer.image('http://highcharts.com/demo/gfx/snow.png', 334, 40, 20, 20).add();
});
```

Basic DEMO (Not scaled properly): http://jsfiddle.net/j8Y6g/

---

Related Questions:
[highchart: add images to top of chart on every column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8703835/highchart-add-images-to-top-of-chart-on-every-column) (I preferred this one)
[Highcharts: Adding clickable image to every xAxis gridLine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794682/highcharts-adding-clickable-image-to-every-xaxis-gridline)

Other Question:
[Custom HighCharts - change the height of plotLines , show the marker value by default at a specific x and y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168845/custom-highcharts-change-the-height-of-plotlines-show-the-marker-value-by-de)

Answer (score 3):

This can be done. See this [demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-symbols/gray/).
Use code per point like:

```
...
    {
      y: 26.5,
      marker: {
        symbol: 'url(<your image>)'
      }
    }
...
```

Comment: It looks similar to what I want... do points of a series have some kind of onRender event so I can modify it to look like my screenshot?

Comment: Not really sure what you mean. You  make an image and it appears at the yValue point you provide. What is required for your `onRender` event?

Answer (score 0):

```
        marker: {
            symbol: 'square'
        },
        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, {
            y: 26.5,
            marker: {
                symbol: 'url('your image path here')'
            }
        }, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
```

HighCharts Reference

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/spline-symbols/