# How can i show image on group columns highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a group chart

[image]

I want to show images on top of each[image]

So there are only two images, so the value in xaxis subcategories if the value is negative i want to show image2 and if value is positive show image1

I have seen this answer but cant figure out this in group chart

[highchart: add images to top of chart on every column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8703835/highchart-add-images-to-top-of-chart-on-every-column)

My group chart Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/KWPsv/90/

My Code:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
  colors: [
    '#5a9bd4',
    '#faa75b',
    '#7ac36a',
    '#9e67ab',
    '#f15a60',
    '#ce7058',
    '#d77fb4'
  ]
});

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    type: 'column'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Chart Title'
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  legend: {},
  tooltip: {
    shared: true,
    formatter: function() {
      var s = [],
        xAxis = this.points[0].series.xAxis,
        categoryIndex = xAxis.categories.indexOf(this.x),
        title = this.x,
        subTitle = xAxis.options.subtitles[categoryIndex];
      s.push(title + '<br>');
      s.push(subTitle + '<br>');
      $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
        s.push('<span style="color:#D31B22;font-weight:bold;">' + point.series.name + ' : ' +
          point.y + '<span>');
      });

      return s.join(' and ');
    },
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      shadow: false,
      borderWidth: 0,
      pointPadding: 0
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    subtitles: ['2', '-1', '4', '-3', '7'],
    categories: ['MainTask 1', 'MainTask2', 'MainTask3', 'MainTask4', 'MainTask5'],
    lineColor: '#999',
    lineWidth: 1,
    tickColor: '#666',
    tickLength: 3,
    title: {
      text: 'X Axis Title',
      style: {
        color: '#333'
      }
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    lineColor: '#999',
    lineWidth: 1,
    tickColor: '#666',
    tickWidth: 1,
    tickLength: 3,
    gridLineColor: '#ddd',
    title: {
      text: 'Y Axis Title',
      rotation: 0,
      margin: 50,
      style: {
        color: '#333'
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    y: 0,
    mydata: 10,
    name: 'Designation 1',
    data: [7, 12, 16, 32, 64]
  }, {
    y: 0,

    mydata: 20,
    name: 'Designation 2',
    data: [16, 32, 64, 7, 12]
  }, {
    y: 0,

    mydata: 30,
    name: 'Designation 3',
    data: [32, 64, 7, 12, 16],
  }, {
    mydata: 13,
    name: 'Designation 4',
    data: [7, 12, 16, 32, 64]
  }, {
    y: 0,

    mydata: 23,
    name: 'Designation 5',
    data: [16, 32, 64, 7, 12]
  }, {
    y: 0,

    mydata: 22,
    name: 'Designation 6',
    data: [32, 64, 7, 12, 16]
  }]
















});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `Renderer.image` to add an image on a chart. You can do that for example on `load` event.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Renderer.image

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/kudxL3kh/

Comment: Actuallyi want image with respect to some data

Comment: You can get x and y value of each point, change it to pixel value using Axis.toPixels() function (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Axis.toPixels) and render an image using this coordinates. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/9m1fkkxm/.

Comment: actually i want the image on condition base if the value in subtitle is negative show image 1 and if it is positive show image 2

Comment: I gave you an example how to simply add an image to a chart. When they display or on what conditions, is up to you. You can add an adequate conditions by yourself, for example in the load event.